# Como acceder a una variable dentro de otra sin saber a esta definida la anterior

Tags: angularjs

Por ejemplo, tengo un if en el que quiero entrar si una determinada variable que esta dentro de un array esta definida.

```
if(angular.isDefined(ficha.equipo.color)){
  console.log(ficha.equipo.color);
}
```

Lo que pasa es que da error si no hago lo siguiente.

```
if(angular.isDefined(ficha) && angular.isDefined(ficha.equipo) && 
    angular.isDefined(ficha.equipo.color)){
  console.log(ficha.equipo.color);
}
```

¿Hay alguna manera de que con una sola comprobación de angular.isDefined compruebe todo el camino de variables hasta llegar a la ultima?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No creo que angular ni ningún otro framework pueda hacer eso, en el core de javascript, si accedes a una propiedad en un objeto indefinido se lanza una excepción.

Una alternativa sería hacer tu propia función para comprobar  el path hasta una propiedad:

```js
function checkPath(path, obj) {
  let _obj = obj;
  while (path.length) {
    const p = path.shift();
    if ((!path.length && p) && !_obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
      return false;
    }
  _obj = _obj[p];
  }
  return true;
}
```

Donde `path` sería el 'camino' hasta la propiedad que quieres comprobar y `obj` el objeto donde quieres comprobar ese camino.

En tu caso: `checkPath(['equipo', 'color'], ficha);`

Comment: De hecho, el código de esa función es simplemente: `function isDefined(o) {
  return typeof o !== 'undefined');
}`

Comment: No funcionaria para los casos donde necesites comprobar propiedades. Por ejemplo, tu función no se podría llamar para comprobar la propiedad color en el objeto de la pregunta, `ficha.equipo.color`. Si ficha o equipo fuese indefinido se lanzaría una excepción

Comment: Es que no funciona: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27818331/what-is-the-benefit-of-angular-isdefined

Comment: El código lo puedes ver [aquí](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L509)

Comment: Perdona, no había entendido a lo que te referías.

Comment: Ahora que lo releo es normal, no especifiqué que me refería a la función de Angular, no a la tuya.